# Template in angular component not working as expected.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my index.html file.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="phone-list.component.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>

        <!-- Use a custom component to render a list of phones -->
        <phone-list></phone-list>

      </body>
    </html>
```

This is my phone-list.component.js file

```
// Register 'phoneList' component, along with it's associated controller and template'

angular.
  module('phonecatApp').
  component('phoneList', {
    template: 
      '<ul>' + 
      '<li ng-repeat="phone in $ctrl.phones">' + 
      '<span>{{phone.name}}</span>' + 
      '<p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>' + 
      '</li>' + 
      '</ul>' + '<h3>To be honest, my real name is {{me.name}}</h3>', 
      controller: function phoneListController() {
        this.phones = [
          {
            name:'Nexus 5', 
            snippet: 'Fast just got faster with Nexus 5'
          }, 
          {
            name: 'Motorolla Xoom with Wi-Fi', 
            snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation Tablet'
          },
          {
            name: 'Motorolla Xoom', 
            snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation Tablet'
          }
        ];

        this.me = [
          {
            name: 'shameem',
            age: 18
          }
        ]

      }
  });
```

me.name should be displayed in the phone-list component in index.html page. 
I do not understand as to why me.name is not displayed in the page.

Comment: what  error u r getting exeactl

Comment: I'm not getting an error.

Comment: My name is not displayed in the index.html page.

Comment: I this is ur Error '<h3>To be honest, my real name is {{me.name}}</h3>',

Comment: Yes. But why isn't me.name displayed ??

Comment: You need to define scope

Comment: Here u never used wat is 'me' so as mentioned Paulson u need define $scope otherwise  replace This  {{phone.name}}

Answer (score 1):

Please use following code

```
'</ul>' + '<h3>To be honest, my real name is {{$ctrl.me[0].name}}</h3>',
```

Instead of

```
'</ul>' + '<h3>To be honest, my real name is {{$ctrl.me.name}}</h3>',
```

This issue is because you are using array object and trying to access it directly. Or else you can use ng-repeat

Or Else Make

```
this.me =  {name: 'shameem', age: 18}
```

Instead of

```
this.me =  [{name: 'shameem', age: 18}]
```

and can use your same HTML if you change "this.me" to object instead of array

Comment: I tried using calling it as an object as well, but still, the name is not being displayed. .

Comment: Are you able to print this.phones in HTML?

Comment: Change to {{$ctrl.me[0].name}} instead of {{me[0].name}}.

Comment: Yes, I am able to print this.phones in HTML

Comment: Or if object change {{$ctrl.me.name}} instead of {{me.name}}. This will work!!